# Undefined control sequence. Unmatched brace?

Tags: bibtex

Here's a minimal viable example of my error. `*.tex` file first:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,man,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\title{Minimal example of my error}
\shorttitle{Minimal}
\author{Rick O. Gilmore}
\affiliation{{The Pennsylvania State University}}
\abstract{This is pretty abstract.}
\authornote{Rick O. Gilmore is still learning how to use LaTeX.}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction to a very short paper. I'd like to cite this book    \cite{borgman_big_2015} and this article \cite{boyd_critical_2012}.
\section{Conclusion}
The bibliography prints properly, but the in-text citations do not. 
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

And associated `*.bib` file:

```
@book{borgman_big_2015,
  title = {Big {Data}, {Little} {Data}, {No} {Data}},
  isbn = {9780262028561},
  url = {https://mitpress.mit.edu/big-data},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  author = {Borgman, Christine},
  year = {2015}
}
@article{boyd_critical_2012,
title = {Critical {Questions} for {Big} {Data}},
  volume = {15},
  issn = {1369-118X},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/1369118X.2012.678878},
  number = {5},
  urldate = {2015-07-27},
  journal = {Information, Communication \& Society},
  author = {boyd, danah and Crawford, Kate},
  month = {June},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {662--679},
}
```

I am getting a series of errors associated with the `\cite{}` commands:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                               and this one, too \cite{b...

?
! Argument of \@@cite has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                                   and this one, too    \cite{b...

?
Runaway argument?
>{\hyper@link@ }\def \reserved@b {\hyper@link@ [link]}\futurelet \@let@token     \E
TC.
! Paragraph ended before \@@cite was complete.
<to be read again>
               \par
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                                   and this one, too \cite{b...

?
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                               and this one, too \cite{b...

?
! Argument of \@@cite has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                               and this one, too \cite{b...

?
Runaway argument?
>{\hyper@link@ }\def \reserved@b {\hyper@link@ [link]}\futurelet \@let@token     \E
TC.
! Paragraph ended before \@@cite was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.16 ...to cite this paper \cite{borgman_big_2015}
                                               and this one, too \cite{b...

?
```

Thanks in advance for helping me sort out what I am sure is a simple error on my part.

Comment: This might be due to your package load order, or package interaction. Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the result?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  all the errors refer to the same line, so the ones after the first are likely to be bogus.  as already pointed out, the problem of the unrecognized control sequence, since it is triggered by a `\cite` and refers to a hyperlinking command, may well be due to package load order; `hyperref` must be one of the last packages loaded, with very few exceptions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `apacite` is one of those exceptions. One of the reasons, i wouldn't personally rely on that package.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and for me it was fixed by putting

`\usepackage{hyperref}`

BEFORE

`\usepackage{apacite}`

I am not sure how this would work for the example you posted in the question, since I don't see any `\usepackage{apacite}` (but I do see apacite in the `\documentclass` at top). Even if it doesn't work for you, it may still help others that find this question through googling

Comment: Similar answer that points to manual of `apacite` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316288/208474)