# Compile error with \href ToC and \apacite

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, compiling, apacite

I would like to edit my document but I have a compile error somewhere between the `\href` and the `apacite` but can't locate it. I've tried blocking out code and taking out references, with varying results.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% TOC, Citations, Refereneces, and Appendicies
\usepackage{apacite} % \cite{ref1,ref2}
%Warning - unsupported tocstyle code
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}.}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\urlstyle{same}
%\hypersetup{
%   colorlinks=true,
%   urlcolor=cyan,
%   linkcolor=blue,
%   citecolor=green,
%   filecolor=magenta,
%   pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
%   pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
%}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}   
...to be installed \cite{church13,hershkowits97}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here are the `bibliography.bib` entries then

```
@ARTICLE{church13,
   author       = {K.H. Church and H. Tsang and R. Rodrigiguez and P. Defembaugh and R. Rumpf},
   year         = 2013,
   title        = {Printed circuit structures, the evolution of printed circuit boards},
   journal      = {Circuit Insight},
   volume       = {},
   number       = {},
   pages        = {},
   howpublished = {}, 
   url          = {http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm},
}

@ARTICLE{hershkowits97,
   author       = {N. Hershkowits and R.A. Breun},
   year         = {1997},
   title        = {Diagnostics for plasma processing (etch plasmas) (invited)},
   journal      = {Review of Scientific Instrumentation},
   volume       = {68},
   number       = {1},
   pages        = {880--885},
   howpublished = {},
}
```

Comment: Welcome! We can't compile without the bib entries.

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded the .bib text. I thought about that too about an hour ago, lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `apacite` manual clearly states on page 47, Section 8.2:

> The hyperref package turns (cross-) references into hypertext links.
>   This can be used in conjunction with a program such as LATEX2HTML to
>   compose .html files with clickable links, to internet pages or within
>   the same document, or it can be used to create a .pdf document with
>   clickable crossreferences. Evidently, citations are also references.
>   Therefore, the hyperref package transforms these into hypertext links
>   as well, and needs to redefine the citation commands and reference list
>   commands in order to do so. These redefinitions have caused severe
>   incompatibility problems between apacite and hyperref in the past.
>   These incompatibility problems have been solved and apacite is
>   compatible with hyperref, provided that apacite is loaded **after**
>   hyperref.

→ load `apacite` after `hyperref`.

Please make sure to delete old the `.aux` and `*.blg` and `.bbl` files before recompiling here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% TOC, Citations, Refereneces, and Appendicies
%
%Warning - unsupported tocstyle code
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\roman{subsubsection}.}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{church13,
   author       = {K.H. Church and H. Tsang and R. Rodrigiguez and P. Defembaugh and R. Rumpf},
   year         = 2013,
   title        = {Printed circuit structures, the evolution of printed circuit boards},
   journal      = {Circuit Insight},
   volume       = {},
   number       = {},
   pages        = {},
   howpublished = {}, 
   url          = {http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm},
}

@ARTICLE{hershkowits97,
   author       = {N. Hershkowits and R.A. Breun},
   year         = {1997},
   title        = {Diagnostics for plasma processing (etch plasmas) (invited)},
   journal      = {Review of Scientific Instrumentation},
   volume       = {68},
   number       = {1},
   pages        = {880--885},
   howpublished = {},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   urlcolor=cyan,
   linkcolor=blue,
   citecolor=green,
   filecolor=magenta,
   pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
   pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}

\usepackage{apacite} % \cite{ref1,ref2}

\begin{document}   
...to be installed \cite{church13,hershkowits97}.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Clearly I never read the manual, mostly due to my spare time being taken up with studying chemistry and physics and GRE and research and well, college life. But thank you for the reference.

Comment: @MatthewOlson: Well, yes ... I hope you won't be disappointed one day if nobody reads a potential manual written by you then ;-)