# Undefined control sequence caused by citations when using hyperref

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, citing, urls

I am relatively new to LaTeX and most of my answers have been solved with some quick googling, but this specific problem has left me scratching my head with its specificity.

I am writing a paper and trying to include some hyperlinks, so I imported hyperref which caused many of the citations I used to create the following three errors:

1. **! Undefined control sequence.\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a\relax@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp... ...ies them out \cite{Griff_1997, Natura2000}**
2. **! Argument of @@cite has an extra }.\par ...ies them out \cite{Griff_1997, Natura2000}**
3. **! Paragraph ended before @@cite was complete.\par ...ies them out \cite{Griff_1997, Natura2000}**

My preamble is defined as:

```latex
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%to wrap the urls in the references
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\font\myfont=cmr12 at 28pt

\font\myfontini=cmr12 at 20pt
\font\myfontinini=cmr12 at 18pt

\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
```

With an example of the first created error being

```latex
\begin{document}

Mediterranean temporary ponds (MTPs) are bodies of water under 10 hectares which
 exist across southern Europe as ephemeral habitat and home to many creatures
 which have evolved to the annual cycle which dries them out \cite{Griff_1997, 
Natura2000}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{testref}

\end{document}
```

and my bibtex for those two entries being

```
@report{Natura2000,
author = {Ernesto Ruiz},
title = {Management of {N}atura 2000 habitats $*$ {M}editerranean temporary ponds 3170},
institution = {European Commission},
year = {2008},
OPTlanguage = {EN},
url = {https://ec.europa.eu/environment/nature/natura2000/management/habitats/pdf/3170_Mediterranean_temporary_ponds.pdf},
}

@article{Griff_1997,
author = {Griffiths, R. A.},
title = {Temporary ponds as amphibian habitats},
journal = {Aquatic Conservation: Marine and Freshwater Ecosystems},
volume = {7},
number = {2},
pages = {119-126},
doi = {10.1002/(SICI)1099-0755(199706)7:2<119::AID-AQC223>3.0.CO;2-4},
url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/\%28SICI\%291099-0755\%28199706\%297\%3A2\%3C119\%3A\%3AAID-AQC223\%3E3.0.CO\%3B2-4},
year = {1997}
}
```

Perhaps it is just something small that I am not noticing, but I would appreciate any help in this matter. Thank you!

Comment: Try deleting all generated files (.aux .bbl, etc.) and compiling again. Does the problem go away?

Comment: Actually, I think you just need to change the package loading order. Load `apacite` after `hyperref` ([details](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316288/2417)).

Comment: Moving the apacite worked, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Since the same issue is addressed under [Compile error with \href ToC and \apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316218/2417), I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate.